# null shorthand in C#?

Tags: c#, null

Is there a way to make this line shorter?

```
bool pass = d != null && d["k"] != null && (bool)d["k"];
```

Note: "k" is actually "a longer id"; I replaced it to make it more readable in this post.  Many of your suggestions don't check whether d is null.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool pass = d != null && (bool)(d["k"] ?? false);
```

Comment: +1 I think this is what he was after, the ?? operator. Still needs the check for d as null as well though. I've always thought it'd be nice to have a cascading ?? operator, however, I can see plenty of reasons why it would be bad!

Comment: This does not check if the value in the dictionary exists. If crashes on a null-ref exception if "k" is not there.

Comment: @Jan No, it does not. If d["k"] returns null, right-hand side of a ?? operator (which is "false") gets converted to bool.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the "key not found" exception.

Comment: Jan, if Anton's code crashes, then so did the original code. That's not the point of the exercise.

Comment: I hope there's a line starting with // accompanying the line of code?

Answer (score 32):

It is already barely readable, so why make it any shorter?

Comment: Agreed. If anything it should be longer, or at least use better variable and index names.

Comment: Agreed- what do d and k represent?

Comment: Where is the connection? Making it shorter could potentially *improve* readability. Compare `x == null ? "foo" : x` to `x ?? "foo"`. Short == (potentially) concise.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what the asker meant by "shorter". It is a fairly common requirement to check items aren't null before looking at their properties. It would be nice if that could be done without 5-6 nested &&'s

Comment: To improve readability maybe? Shorter doesn't always mean more cryptic.

Answer (score 8):

I would question why you are trying to make it shorter.

Shorter code doesn't benefit anybody. It makes it far harder for someone else to read it.

Personally, I would be asking "how can I make this code easier to read", and the answer to that would be split it up into multiple lines, and only do 1 thing on each line.

The only 'null shorthand' available in C# is the [null-coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator, which allows you to define a default value for a null object. But for your code, I'd recommend aiming for readability, not line size.

Comment: Because the frequent "null" checks get on my nerves, too.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, extract a function from it and call it something like `doTheValuesInTheFooBarDictionaryPassTheRebarTest`.

That's much easier to read.  Of course, the method will still contain your line above, but the reader of the code (from here 'till the end of time) will have a MUCH more pleasant experience when skimming the code.

By making code shorter, what are you hoping to achieve?  Quicker to read?  (it'll take longer for the brain to parse it!).  Quicker to type?  (you type this stuff once and either modify or read it again and again (and again!)). Generally, longer, more descriptive variables are better, and if you can wrap them in an encapsulating method, then do that too.

Comment: I am with Steve here. Giving name to such one liners are very useful when you are reading the code. And yes, the name suggested by the Steve is an example and not the actual name.

Comment: James, it's a 1-liner OF TEXT. Logically, it's a multi-liner: Does this thing exist AND if it does, does it contain a particular field AND if it does, try and coerce it into a boolean value. Without extracting a function, you'll be continually parsing ALL these things (the HOW) rather than just browsing an overview of what you need (the WHAT)

Answer (score 4):

You can get rid of the first expression by initializing d in the constructor. I recommend you to use generic dictionary i.e.

```
Dictionary<string,bool> d = new Dictionary<string,bool>();
```

That way you don't have to cast the value. And use the ContainsKey method as opposed to directly accessing the value. So your final expression

```
bool pass = d.ContainsKey("k") && d["k"];
```

Answer (score 4):

A combination of the null-conditional and null-coalescing operators should work here:

```
bool pass = (bool) (d?["k"] ?? false);
```

To clarify:

- If `d` is null, `d?["k"]` is null
- If `d?["k"]` is null, `d?["k"] ?? false` is `false` (boxed as `object`)
- The result is then cast

An alternative would be to cast *before* the null-coalescing operator, but to cast to a nullable type:

```
bool pass = ((bool?) d?["k"]) ?? false;
```

Note that the null-conditional operator was introduced in C# 6.

Comment: You are my hero bro! I'm learning a lot from you, thank you! :D

Answer (score 3):

I would not try to shorten it further, I would try to give it a nice name. Writing an extension method or modifying the class (if you have access to the code) sounds good to me.

```
// Better use a longer and more descriptive name here.
public static Boolean Pass(this Foo foo, String bar)
{
    return
        (foo != null)
        && (bar != null) // Maybe this test, too?
        && (foo[bar] is Boolean)
        && (foo[bar] as Boolean);
}
```

And use it like that.

```
Boolean pass = d.Pass("k");
```

Answer (score 2):

I would question why you are casting d["k"] to a bool.  Either it is already a bool or it should be compared to something to get a bool.  This would make things clearer.

Anyway, I suppose this might work:

```
bool pass = (d != null) && d["k"] ?? false
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Make d strongly typed (e.g. use Dictionary<> instead of Hashtable)

```
bool pass = d != null && d["k"];
```

It would help if we knew the type of d!

Answer (score 1):

This is not shorter, but more reliable (and perhaps a bit more efficient):

```
bool pass = false;
if (d != null)
{
    object value;
    if (d.TryGetValue("k", out value))
    {
        pass = value is bool && (bool)value;
    }
}
```

I would recommend moving it into a function.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace it with a function call that takes in a dictionary and a key...

Answer (score 1):

I would much prefer to see something like this:

```
bool pass = false;
if(d != null && d["k"] != null)
  pass = (bool)d["k"];
```

or if wanted to write a handy extension method for `System.Object` that would make it look like this:

```
bool pass = false;
if(!d.IsNull && !d["k"].IsNull)
  pass = (bool)d["k"]
```

I find this much more understandable than the original version.

Answer (score 0):

In c# 6 and above you can use

```
bool pass = (bool)(d?["k"] ?? false);
```

If the compile time type of d["k"] is bool? you can omit the cast

```
bool pass = d?["k"] ?? false;
```

Comment: If the compile-time type of `d["k"]` is `object`, this won't work - I assume there's a reason for the cast in the OP's code.